# How to convert rdbms datatypes to nosql datatypes using java

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

I have source datatypes from mysql and target datatypes from mongodb.

If source datatype is varchar,how can I convert into string and set that value to the document using convertToTargetDataType method.Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

```
private Document prepareDoc(ResultSet rs, List<Columns> columns) throws SQLException {
        Document document = new Document();
        for (Columns col : columns) {
            String sourceDataType = col.getSourceDataType();
            String targetDataType = col.getTargetDataType();

            String key = col.getColumnName();
            String value = null;

            switch (sourceDataType) {
            case "varchar": {
                //String value = rs.getString(key);
                document.put(key, convertToTargetDataType(targetDataType, value));
                break;
            }
            case "int": {
                //double value = rs.getDouble(key);
                document.put(key, convertToTargetDataType(targetDataType, value));
                break;
            }

            case "date": {
                //Date value = rs.getDate(key);
                document.put(key, convertToTargetDataType(targetDataType, value));
                break;
            }

            }
        }
        return document;
    }

    public Object convertToTargetDataType(String targetDataType, String value) {
        //if target datatype = value datatype ,return that datatype

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you intend to use MongoDB, it's worth noting that you don't need a sort of predefined type that you use before inserting.

As your objects are dynamic and you don't know the schema beforehand, you could simply append objects from the result set to the document:

```
private Document prepareDoc(ResultSet rs, List<Columns> columns) throws SQLException {
    Document document = new Document();
    for (Columns col : columns) {
        String sourceDataType = col.getSourceDataType();
        String targetDataType = col.getTargetDataType();

        String key = col.getColumnName();

        //The correct JSON type will be used based on the ACTUAL JAVA TYPE RETURNED BY THE DRIVER
        document.put(key, rs.getObject(key));

    }
    return document;
}
```

**NOTE**: It's important to check the concrete classes that the driver gives you for their respective SQL types in the RS. Behaviour can differ, so be sure that your particular RDBMS's JDBC driver gives you something that's usable (esp. if you use dodgy types such as blobs, etc.).
But in general, this should work for the most common types.

Comment: No,I have a predefined schema in the form of json file.Where I have source and target datatypes.I'm reading the source and target datatypes from that file and checking both the datatypes.